# Ruby on Rails: undefined method `new_tech'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, methods, undefined

I have an app where the user can submit a project. For each field they have a choice of either putting in new data into the database, or selecting old data from passed projects to fill that field.

I am having trouble getting this to work for this piece of code in my New view:

```
<%= form_for(@technol) do |tech| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= tech.label :tech %><br />
    <%=  tech.text_field :new_tech, :maxlength => 30 %><br />

    OR<br />

    <%= collection_select(:technols, :id, @all_technols, :id, :tech, {}, {:multiple => true} ) %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

Here is my new and create action:

**New**

```
def new
    @project = Project.new
@technol = Technol.new(params[:tech])

@all_technols = Technol.all
tech_ids = params[:technols][:id].reject(&:blank?) unless params[:technols].nil?


@project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end
```

**Create**

```
def create
    @all_technols = Technol.all
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])
@technol = Technol.new(params[:tech])


    @project.client = params[:new_client] unless params[:new_client].blank?
    @project.project_owner = params[:new_project_owner] unless params[:new_project_owner].blank?

    @technol.tech = params[:new_tech] unless params[:new_tech].blank?

    @project.role = params[:new_role] unless params[:new_role].blank?
    @project.industry = params[:new_industry] unless params[:new_industry].blank?
    @project.business_div = params[:new_business_div] unless params[:new_business_div].blank?


    params[:technol].each_value do |tech|

    technology = Technol.find_or_create_by_tech(tech.strip)

    @project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build(:technol_id => technology.id) 

  end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

With this code, I am getting this error when trying to open the create new project page:

```
NoMethodError in Projects#new

line #261 raised:

undefined method `new_tech' for #<Technol id: nil, tech: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
Extracted source (around line #261):

258: <%= form_for(@technol) do |tech| %>
259: <div class="field">
260:     <%= tech.label :tech %><br />
261:     <%=  tech.text_field :new_tech, :maxlength => 30 %><br />
262: 
263: OR<br />
264:
```

Any ideas? I am a rails noob so please remember this when trying to answer. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check the API for [`text_field`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field)

```
text_field(object_name, method, options = {})
```

the first param is `object_name` which here is `:tech` and not `:new_tech`. `:new_tech` is neither an attribute nor a method of the `tech` object you are iterating on so it fails.

Make the input field matches the same attribute as the label's one

```
<%= tech.label :tech %><br />
<%= tech.text_field :tech, :maxlength => 30 %>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Will that now not be overridden if the user selects something from the drop down menu. I tried to fix this by doing, `@technol.tech = params[:new_tech] unless params[:new_tech].blank?`

Comment: if you still want to use the new_tech field for the user to add some, you can do it by using text_field_tag and not tech.text_field http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag